# Collapse white spaces in Grid React Material Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hi guys i have a quick question for material ui user out there.
Is there any way for collapsing Grid items vertically like on image on the bottom?
Only solution that comes to mind is putting them in two columns but it wont work on bigger or smaller screens because grid isn't always shown in two columns.

```js
const {
  Grid,
  Paper
} = window['material-ui'];

class GridTest extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Grid container xs={12} spacing={8} style={{background:'#eee'}}>
        <Grid item xs={6}><Paper style={{ height: 300}} /></Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}><Paper style={{ height: 100}} /></Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}><Paper style={{ height: 200}} /></Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}><Paper style={{ height: 300}} /></Grid>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <GridTest />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@3.9.2/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

[image: before]

What I'm aiming for:

[image: after]

Sorry for bad grammar I'm rusty as hell :D
Thanks for any info on this

Comment: AFAIK this is not part of React MaterialUI grid. Probably you can give a try to some other library, for example:https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-component

Comment: Hey @KryQ, were you able to figure out a way of achieving this with MUI?

Comment: There is no way in clean mui. uI used mansory library on top